# How to make a link have the gloved hand mouse when hovering

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make mouse pointer a hand when hover over <li> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/make-mouse-pointer-a-hand-when-hover-over-li-element)

I have an input form button when you hover your mouse over it the mouse pointer doesn't change orientation. How can I make a link specify to show the gloved mouse finger pointer?

Answer (score 28):

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Answer (score 8):

I found [This interesting site](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html) about mouse pointer styling for you. Scroll down to pointer W3C.

`cursor: pointer;`

You can hover to test the ones you like and it indicates what browsers it works with.

Answer (score 5):

this is another little example

```
<style type="text/css">
   a.clickable{
       cursor: pointer;
       cursor: hand;
   }
</style>

<a href="#" class="clickable">Link</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

If the link is an anchor  tag it should happen by default. You could use CSS to force it, and then it wouldn't matter what html tag it is.

```
<a href="/Blah.htm" style="cursor: hand;">Blah</a>
```

(See Comments below for important info)

Comment: Drive-by-downvoters: he **did** provide an answer, and not unuseful. You might argue it's an innacurate and badly phrased one, but it's certainly much better than the question. :P

Comment: `cursor: hand` is discontinued and it only works in IE, Opera and nothing else.Therefore this would return a disappointing result as over half of the popular browsers wont work. The one that all browsers use today is `cursor: pointer;`. The only reason you should use it is if you want IE 5.5 and 5.0 to work.

Comment: I stand corrected - proves the importance of downvote-comments. :)

Comment: Thanks for the correction Jonathan. Old habits die hard, and "cursor:hand" its one of those habits that I need to get rid off. I do agree with sr-pt, the down vote makes a whole lot more sense once it is explained.