# How to change the cursor into a hand when a user hovers over a list item?

Tags: css, hover, mouse-cursor

I've got a list, and I have a click handler for its items:

```
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>goo</li>
</ul>
```

How can I change the mouse pointer into a hand pointer (like when hovering over a button)? Right now the pointer turns into a text selection pointer when I hover over the list items.

Comment: FYI, I retagged your question by removing "jquery" and adding "css" to more accurately reflect the nature of your question and the answer to it.

Comment: A good reference list for changing the cursor to a hand and other icons available in css. http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csscursors.shtml

Comment: If there is a click handler that is added with JavaScript also the css for the mouse pointer should be added with JavaScript. So the user does not think he or she could click where it is not possible. I added an appropriate [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22127656/696973) for this.

Comment: Did you try `cursor: grab`

Answer (score 3821, accepted):

In light of the passage of time, as people have mentioned, you can now safely just use:

```css
li { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: It's worth noting that just doing `cursor: pointer` is good enough for everything above IE 5.5: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html

Comment: It's funny how pointer!=cursor and hand!=pointer, adding even more to the confusion. :)

Comment: Of note, http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/cursor.html#note (referenced in an earlier comment) states that hand must come _after_ pointer. I recommend using just pointer - IE 5.5 is deader than IE 6.

Comment: @EdwardBlack it used to be required for odd browsers that weren't standards compliant, the answer was updated long ago to reflect the new way which is simply just `pointer` this question is over 5 years old btw.

Comment: Indeed. Even if you run IE in IE5 compatibility mode, `cursor:pointer` still works. So if there ever was an excuse to use `cursor:hand`, there no longer is.

Comment: And according to CSS 3.0 Validation "cursor:hand" is not a valid value for cursor. We should use just cursor:pointer

Comment: Just use this in whatever HTML element you want the cursor pointer on hover

Answer (score 542):

Use for `li`:

```
li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

See more cursor properties with examples after running snippet option:

[image: An animation showing a cursor hovering over a div of each class]

```css
.auto          { cursor: auto; }
.default       { cursor: default; }
.none          { cursor: none; }
.context-menu  { cursor: context-menu; }
.help          { cursor: help; }
.pointer       { cursor: pointer; }
.progress      { cursor: progress; }
.wait          { cursor: wait; }
.cell          { cursor: cell; }
.crosshair     { cursor: crosshair; }
.text          { cursor: text; }
.vertical-text { cursor: vertical-text; }
.alias         { cursor: alias; }
.copy          { cursor: copy; }
.move          { cursor: move; }
.no-drop       { cursor: no-drop; }
.not-allowed   { cursor: not-allowed; }
.all-scroll    { cursor: all-scroll; }
.col-resize    { cursor: col-resize; }
.row-resize    { cursor: row-resize; }
.n-resize      { cursor: n-resize; }
.e-resize      { cursor: e-resize; }
.s-resize      { cursor: s-resize; }
.w-resize      { cursor: w-resize; }
.ns-resize     { cursor: ns-resize; }
.ew-resize     { cursor: ew-resize; }
.ne-resize     { cursor: ne-resize; }
.nw-resize     { cursor: nw-resize; }
.se-resize     { cursor: se-resize; }
.sw-resize     { cursor: sw-resize; }
.nesw-resize   { cursor: nesw-resize; }
.nwse-resize   { cursor: nwse-resize; }

.cursors > div {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px 2px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    &:nth-child(even) {
       background: #eee;
    }
    &:hover {
       opacity: 0.25
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Example of cursor</h1>

<div class="cursors">
    <div class="auto">auto</div>
    <div class="default">default</div>
    <div class="none">none</div>
    <div class="context-menu">context-menu</div>
    <div class="help">help</div>
    <div class="pointer">pointer</div>
    <div class="progress">progress</div>
    <div class="wait">wait</div>
    <div class="cell">cell</div>
    <div class="crosshair">crosshair</div>
    <div class="text">text</div>
    <div class="vertical-text">vertical-text</div>
    <div class="alias">alias</div>
    <div class="copy">copy</div>
    <div class="move">move</div>
    <div class="no-drop">no-drop</div>
    <div class="not-allowed">not-allowed</div>
    <div class="all-scroll">all-scroll</div>
    <div class="col-resize">col-resize</div>
    <div class="row-resize">row-resize</div>
    <div class="n-resize">n-resize</div>
    <div class="s-resize">s-resize</div>
    <div class="e-resize">e-resize</div>
    <div class="w-resize">w-resize</div>
    <div class="ns-resize">ns-resize</div>
    <div class="ew-resize">ew-resize</div>
    <div class="ne-resize">ne-resize</div>
    <div class="nw-resize">nw-resize</div>
    <div class="se-resize">se-resize</div>
    <div class="sw-resize">sw-resize</div>
    <div class="nesw-resize">nesw-resize</div>
    <div class="nwse-resize">nwse-resize</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Off topic, Using which software you did that gif animation? Waiting..@Santosh Khalse

Comment: @fWd82 check ShareX - record a gif

Comment: I felt this was a useful reminder of cursors and added the code as a tool. Here's a link to the code above: http://spragucm.com/web-css-cursor-pointers/

Comment: Awesome animation!

@fWd82 - Peek is also good for recording gifs of an area of your screen. https://github.com/phw/peek

Answer (score 187):

You do not require jQuery for this, simply use the following CSS content:

```
li {cursor: pointer}
```

And voilà! Handy.

Answer (score 86):

Use:

```
li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Other valid values (which `hand` is **not**) for the current HTML specification can be viewed [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/cursor).

Comment: I don't understand what the use of the `:hover` pseudo class is in this case. Is there any advantage for specifying a different cursor when the mouse does *not* hover the element? Also I read that `li:hover` does not work in IE6.

Comment: I suppose `:hover` is just for specificity, @Robert. I can't test for support in any version of MSIE, sorry, but it wouldn't surprise me if it didn't work! :P

Comment: why is `hand` in the top answer, even though it is not working?

Comment: @EdwardBlack `cursor: hand` is deprecated and not in the css spec. it's like from ie5-6 era. use only `pointer`.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that (in Chrome at least) specifying `element:hover` will take priority, but happen after `element`. What I mean by this is if `cursor` is specified in both `element:hover` and `element` the cursor specified in `element` will flash on the screen for a second before turning to the cursor in `:hover`. While this isn't important for `li` elements as they have no default cursor to start with, if someone wants to change the cursor on an element that already has one (like with `a` elements) they should do so without the `:hover` specifier.

Answer (score 52):

Use

```
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
```

if you want to have a crossbrowser result!

Comment: This is 2018, and cursor:hand is no longer needed for cross-browser development right?

Comment: @Haramoz - yeah, `cursor: hand` is largely obsolete, now. Hasn't been around since IE 5.5.

Comment: It will generate error in css validator

Answer (score 49):

CSS:

```
.auto            { cursor: auto; }
.default         { cursor: default; }
.none            { cursor: none; }
.context-menu    { cursor: context-menu; }
.help            { cursor: help; }
.pointer         { cursor: pointer; }
.progress        { cursor: progress; }
.wait            { cursor: wait; }
.cell            { cursor: cell; }
.crosshair       { cursor: crosshair; }
.text            { cursor: text; }
.vertical-text   { cursor: vertical-text; }
.alias           { cursor: alias; }
.copy            { cursor: copy; }
.move            { cursor: move; }
.no-drop         { cursor: no-drop; }
.not-allowed     { cursor: not-allowed; }
.all-scroll      { cursor: all-scroll; }
.col-resize      { cursor: col-resize; }
.row-resize      { cursor: row-resize; }
.n-resize        { cursor: n-resize; }
.e-resize        { cursor: e-resize; }
.s-resize        { cursor: s-resize; }
.w-resize        { cursor: w-resize; }
.ns-resize       { cursor: ns-resize; }
.ew-resize       { cursor: ew-resize; }
.ne-resize       { cursor: ne-resize; }
.nw-resize       { cursor: nw-resize; }
.se-resize       { cursor: se-resize; }
.sw-resize       { cursor: sw-resize; }
.nesw-resize     { cursor: nesw-resize; }
.nwse-resize     { cursor: nwse-resize; }
```

You can also have the cursor be an image:

```
.img-cur {
   cursor: url(images/cursor.png), auto;
}
```

Comment: It is not an answer to the question.

Comment: this maybe not the direct answer to the question but this is a very good guideline. thanks by the way!

Answer (score 24):

I think it would be smart to only show the hand/pointer cursor when JavaScript is available. So people will not have the feeling they can click on something that is not clickable.

To achieve that you could use the JavaScript libary jQuery to add the CSS to the element like so

```
$("li").css({"cursor":"pointer"});
```

Or chain it directly to the click handler.

Or when [modernizer](http://modernizr.com/) in combination with `<html class="no-js">` is used, the CSS would look like this:

```
.js li { cursor: pointer; }
```

Answer (score 23):

```
li:hover {cursor: hand; cursor: pointer;}
```

Answer (score 22):

For complete cross browser, use:

```
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
```

Answer (score 22):

Just for completeness:

```
cursor: -webkit-grab;
```

It also gives a hand, the one you know when moving the view of an image around.

It is quite useful if you want to [emulate grab behavior](https://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/uzGvy) using jQuery and mousedown.

[image]

Answer (score 20):

You can change it either on hover or just specify `cursor:pointer` on list item, both will work.

```
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Alternatively

```
ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Simply put this code.

```css
li{cursor: pointer;}
```

Answer (score 16):

For being able to make anything get the "mousechange" treatment, you can add a CSS class:

```css
.mousechange:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span class="mousechange">Some text here</span>
```

I would not say to use `cursor:hand` since it was only valid for Internet Explorer 5.5 and below, and Internet Explorer 6 came with Windows XP (2002). People will only get the hint to upgrade when their browser stops working for them. Additionally, in Visual Studio, it will red underline that entry. It tells me:

> Validation (CSS 3.0): "hand" is not a valid value for the "cursor"
>   property

Answer (score 15):

Simply just do something like this:

```
li { 
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I apply it on your code to see how it works:

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>goo</li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** Also **DO not** forget you can have any hand cursor with customised cursor, you can create fav hand icon like this one for example:

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  cursor: url(http://findicons.com/files/icons/1840/free_style/128/hand.png) 4 12, auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

```
ul li:hover{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

All of the other responses suggest using the standard CSS pointer, however, there are two methods:

1. Apply the CSS property `cursor:pointer;` to the elements. (This is the default style when a cursor hovers over a button.)
2. Apply the CSS property `cursor:url(pointer.png);` using a custom graphic for your pointer. This may be more desirable if you want to ensure that the user experience is identical on all platforms (instead of allowing the browser/OS decide what your pointer cursor should look like). Note that fallback options may be added in case the image is not found, including secondary urls or any of the other options i.e. `cursor:url(pointer.png,fallback.png,pointer);`

Of course these may be applied to the list items in this manner `li{cursor:pointer;}`, as a class `.class{cursor:pointer;}`, or as a value for the style attribute of each element `style="cursor:pointer;"`.

Answer (score 10):

Use:

```
ul li:hover{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

For more mouse events, check [CSS cursor property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp).

Comment: Duplicate answer. Should've added the link as an edit to the other answer dated Dec. 21, 2014 by user3776645.

Answer (score 7):

You can use one of the following:

```
li:hover
{
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

or

```
li
{
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Working example 1:

```css
    li:hover
    {
     cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

Working example 2:

```css
    li
    {
     cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

For a basic hand symbol:

Try

```
cursor: pointer
```

If you want a hand symbol like drag some item and drop it, try:

```
cursor: grab
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the code below:

`li:hover { cursor: pointer; }`

Answer (score 5):

Check the following. I get it from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp).

```css
.alias { cursor: alias; }
.all-scroll { cursor: all-scroll; }
.auto { cursor: auto; }
.cell { cursor: cell; }
.context-menu { cursor: context-menu; }
.col-resize { cursor: col-resize; }
.copy { cursor: copy; }
.crosshair { cursor: crosshair; }
.default { cursor: default; }
.e-resize { cursor: e-resize; }
.ew-resize { cursor: ew-resize; }
.grab {
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}
.grabbing {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}
.help { cursor: help; }
.move { cursor: move; }
.n-resize { cursor: n-resize; }
.ne-resize { cursor: ne-resize; }
.nesw-resize { cursor: nesw-resize; }
.ns-resize { cursor: ns-resize; }
.nw-resize { cursor: nw-resize; }
.nwse-resize { cursor: nwse-resize; }
.no-drop { cursor: no-drop; }
.none { cursor: none; }
.not-allowed { cursor: not-allowed; }
.pointer { cursor: pointer; }
.progress { cursor: progress; }
.row-resize { cursor: row-resize; }
.s-resize { cursor: s-resize; }
.se-resize { cursor: se-resize; }
.sw-resize { cursor: sw-resize; }
.text { cursor: text; }
.url { cursor: url(myBall.cur), auto; }
.w-resize { cursor: w-resize; }
.wait { cursor: wait; }
.zoom-in { cursor: zoom-in; }
.zoom-out { cursor: zoom-out; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>The cursor property</h1>
  <p>Mouse over the words to change the mouse cursor.</p>
  <p class="alias">alias</p>
  <p class="all-scroll">all-scroll</p>
  <p class="auto">auto</p>
  <p class="cell">cell</p>
  <p class="context-menu">context-menu</p>
  <p class="col-resize">col-resize</p>
  <p class="copy">copy</p>
  <p class="crosshair">crosshair</p>
  <p class="default">default</p>
  <p class="e-resize">e-resize</p>
  <p class="ew-resize">ew-resize</p>
  <p class="grab">grab</p>
  <p class="grabbing">grabbing</p>
  <p class="help">help</p>
  <p class="move">move</p>
  <p class="n-resize">n-resize</p>
  <p class="ne-resize">ne-resize</p>
  <p class="nesw-resize">nesw-resize</p>
  <p class="ns-resize">ns-resize</p>
  <p class="nw-resize">nw-resize</p>
  <p class="nwse-resize">nwse-resize</p>
  <p class="no-drop">no-drop</p>
  <p class="none">none</p>
  <p class="not-allowed">not-allowed</p>
  <p class="pointer">pointer</p>
  <p class="progress">progress</p>
  <p class="row-resize">row-resize</p>
  <p class="s-resize">s-resize</p>
  <p class="se-resize">se-resize</p>
  <p class="sw-resize">sw-resize</p>
  <p class="text">text</p>
  <p class="url">url</p>
  <p class="w-resize">w-resize</p>
  <p class="wait">wait</p>
  <p class="zoom-in">zoom-in</p>
  <p class="zoom-out">zoom-out</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

## Using an HTML Hack

***Note: this is not recommended as it is considered bad practice***

Wrapping the content in an anchor tag containing an `href` attribute will work without explicitly applying the `cursor: pointer;` property with the side effect of anchor properties (amended with CSS):

```html
<a href="#" style="text-decoration: initial; color: initial;"><div>This is bad practice, but it works.</div></a>
```

Comment: This does _not_ work. Anchor tags only have a pointer cursor with underline and a different colour if they have a href.

Comment: "How can I make the cursor a hand when a user hovers over a list item?" - For this particular question, it does. But as pointed out by @sandrooco not a good practice.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the following style:

```
li {
    cursor: grabbing;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just use CSS style for this.

```
li { cursor: pointer; }
```

Answer (score 4):

css

```
li:hover { cursor:pointer }
```

bootsrap

```
<a href="#" class="pe-auto">This link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

## just using CSS to set customize the cursor pointer

```css
/* Keyword value */
cursor: pointer;
cursor: auto;

/* URL, with a keyword fallback */
cursor: url(hand.cur), pointer;

/* URL and coordinates, with a keyword fallback */
cursor: url(cursor1.png) 4 12, auto;
cursor: url(cursor2.png) 2 2, pointer;

/* Global values */
cursor: inherit;
cursor: initial;
cursor: unset;
```

```css
/* 2 URLs and coordinates, with a keyword fallback */

cursor: url(one.svg) 2 2, url(two.svg) 5 5, progress;
```

### demo

> Note: cursor support for many format icons!

such as `.cur, .png, .svg, .jpeg, .webp`, and so on

```css
li:hover{
  cursor: url("https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/cursor/mouse.cur"), pointer;
  color: #0f0;
  background: #000;
}


/*

li:hover{
  cursor: url("../icons/hand.cur"), pointer;
}

*/

li{
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

### refs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.para{
    color: black;
}
.para:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: blue;
}
</style>
<div class="para">
```

> In the above HTML code [:hover] is used to indicate that the following style must be applied only on hovering or keeping the mouse cursor on it.

**There are several types of cursors available in CSS:**

> View the below code for types of cursor:

```
<style>
.alias {cursor: alias;}
.all-scroll {cursor: all-scroll;}
.auto {cursor: auto;}
.cell {cursor: cell;}
.context-menu {cursor: context-menu;}
.col-resize {cursor: col-resize;}
.copy {cursor: copy;}
.crosshair {cursor: crosshair;}
.default {cursor: default;}
.e-resize {cursor: e-resize;}
.ew-resize {cursor: ew-resize;}
.grab {cursor: -webkit-grab; cursor: grab;}
.grabbing {cursor: -webkit-grabbing; cursor: grabbing;}
.help {cursor: help;}
.move {cursor: move;}
.n-resize {cursor: n-resize;}
.ne-resize {cursor: ne-resize;}
.nesw-resize {cursor: nesw-resize;}
.ns-resize {cursor: ns-resize;}
.nw-resize {cursor: nw-resize;}
.nwse-resize {cursor: nwse-resize;}
.no-drop {cursor: no-drop;}
.none {cursor: none;}
.not-allowed {cursor: not-allowed;}
.pointer {cursor: pointer;}
.progress {cursor: progress;}
.row-resize {cursor: row-resize;}
.s-resize {cursor: s-resize;}
.se-resize {cursor: se-resize;}
.sw-resize {cursor: sw-resize;}
.text {cursor: text;}
.url {cursor: url(myBall.cur),auto;}
.w-resize {cursor: w-resize;}
.wait {cursor: wait;}
.zoom-in {cursor: zoom-in;}
.zoom-out {cursor: zoom-out;}
</style>
```

> Click the below link for viewing how the cursor property acts:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor

Answer (score 1):

it's equivalent class in tailwindcss is `cursor-pointer'.