# make <a> tag hover change mouse style

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make mouse pointer a hand when hover over <li> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/make-mouse-pointer-a-hand-when-hover-over-li-element)

Basically, I am using a javascript library that makes tables sortable by clicking on the table head. I have had no experience with javascript myself.The only problem is, clicking on the table is not the most intuitive thing to do. Therefore, I want to make it look like a link. I have made it underlined, but it is still not particularly obvious because when you hover over it, the mouse does not change how it looks. I would like to change the mouse image to the hand that you get when you hover over a link. Currently, the ones which I want to look like links are just a blank  (no href). Is there any way to easily do this, would it involve javascript, and does anyone know how?

Comment: Actually, if you have `<a>` tags, the simple solution is to add the href attribute. Either `<a href="#">` or `<a href="">` and block the default link action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is indeed solvable by using *javascript* but instead you should turn to the power of *CSS*.

If the element you are actually wanting to make *on hover change cursor* is indeed a `<a>` you are better off adding the attribute `href` with a value of *"#"* to make the browser handle the cursor change automatically.

```
<a href="#">I'm a real link, but pressing me won't lead to another webpage</a>
```

---

#### Example snippet (using CSS)

```
<html>
  <head>

    <style>
      th:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
      }   
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <table border="1">
      <tr> <th>Header 1</th> <!-- --> <th>Header 2</th> </tr>
      <tr> <td>value 1 </td> <!-- --> <td>value 2 </td> </tr>
    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

<sup>**[jsFiddle Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QHeDa/1/)**</sup>

Comment: it should be cursor:pointer, there is no such thing as hand in CSS

Comment: @AkashKava thanks, snippet fixed.

Comment: Its strange, pointer should be an arrow and hand should be for hand, but WWC is like government, they hardly listen to people.

Comment: Hand works for some vintage IE version, 6 I believe.

Comment: Thanks :). I was really looking for something that used either CSS or HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS add this:

```
a {
      cursor: pointer;
}
```

You could also consider using a hover effect.

Having thought about it some more, you must be using the `a` tag incorrectly. href is always required and should never be left blank therefore use `<a href="#">link</a>`. Which will solve your problem.