# Anchor link click-able area using css - IE issue

Tags: html, css

I have a menu as follows, I need to enable entire anchor area to be clickable, unfortunately it seems to none.

HTML

```
<div><a href='#'>Home</a></div>    
<div><a href='#'>Contact us</a></div>    
<div><a href='#'>Feedback</a></div>    
<div><a href='#'>Products</a></div>
```

CSS

```
div {height:40px; padding-top:5px; border:#999 solid 1px; margin-bottom:5px;}
a{color:#FFF; font-size:15px;text-shadow: -1px -2px 2px #212121; filter: dropshadow(color=#212121, offx=-1, offy=-2); padding: 13px 0 0 16px; display:block; height:25px; width:100%; zoom:1; line-height: 30px;  }
```

Fiddle as http://jsfiddle.net/3Hyty/2/

**Updated: Problem really in IE**

Comment: Seems fine to me. Why don't you think it's working?

Comment: @j08691 Its IE related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a{
  margin:0 10px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  color:#F00; 
  font-size:15px;
  text-shadow: -1px -2px 2px #212121; padding: 0 0; 
  height:25px; 
  zoom:1; 
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

It was able to do with float left

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is fine, the issue is the jsfiddle blocks link clicks by default unless they open in a new tab.  Make the links have

```
target='_blank'
```

and they work in jsfiddle as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/V3qML/1/.

Obviously for your production environment just use your code as is :)

Answer (score 0):

Add an onClick to the div and style the div to use cursor:hand or cursor:pointer depending on browser see [How can I make the cursor a hand when a user hovers over a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/make-mouse-pointer-a-hand-when-hover-over-li-element)

Applied to your jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3Hyty/5/

The operative line being:

```
<div onClick="javascript:document.location.href='#';" style="cursor:hand;cursor: pointer;">Feedback</div>
```

Comment: This will not work if JavaScript is disabled and is completely unnecessary use of JavaScript when it can be achieved purely through HTML/CSS

Comment: I guess it depends on what the poster is trying to do.  I'm assuming you wanted the entire div to be clickable.  You will also need to style text of the "link" to be consistent with the others.  Does that assumption make the answer less valid?

Comment: It's the inline javascript that makes this a bad answer, not your assumption that the entire div should be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 allows for block elements inside anchors, which forces the anchor to the dimensions of the block element inside it. Alternatively, use spans and style them inline-block or block:

```
<a href='#'><div>Home</div></a>
```

or:

```
<a href='#'><span class="block">Home</span></a>

<style>
span.block {display: block;}
</style>
```

Comment: Why not just display the anchor as a block and avoid a meaningless tag?

Comment: Without knowing the source of the markup, I can't suggest that. It's certainly an option.