# Why is the hand cursor not showing in anchor tag when hovered?

Tags: html

I have this markup, a label wrapped in an anchor tag, but the cursor doesn't change to the hand cursor when you hover over it:

```
<a href="#17">
  <label class="autor">
    <span class="by">
      by 
    </span>
    Erwin Lutzer
  </label>
</a>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-a-hand-when-a-user-hovers-over-a-list-item

Comment: When you click on it does it work?

Comment: I disagree with that "possible duplicate" (see my answer).

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The label is cancelling out the pointer, so make sure your CSS has `cursor: pointer;` for both the a and the label:

```
a,
a label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Or better yet, **remove the label**! It's not valid to have a label inside an anchor.

Answer (score 35):

Not the answer for actual question, but solution to my own, similar problem:

*hand cursor is not showing when hover link.* 
The problem was in the lack of *href* attribute.

```
<a>Link</a>  <!-- regular cursor -->
```

but

```
<a href="#">Link</a>  <!-- cursor pointer -->
```

Comment: Lack of href attribute is valid in html5 and is considered a link placeholder. The pointer cursor, however, needs to be forced via style rules.

Comment: Awesome... Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

There's no reason to put a `label` element in a `a` element. The `label` element is here to decorate an input. There's no way for this `label` to be semantically correct inside a link. As you didn't specify a `for` attribute linking to an input, there is no reason for it to show the behavior of an activable element.

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element)

Don't use CSS here to add a cursor, this would be semantically incorrect. Replace your label with a `span`.

Comment: i used an anchor to wrap the label because if the screen is X pixels width i am going to use the unwrap() jquery function to remove the anchor tag

Comment: @kastulo I don't get what problem you're trying to solve, but that doesn't seem to be the right solution.

Comment: im making a responsive website, and when its 480px or lower, i dont want that anchor tag on my markup, i intend to use unwrap() to remove that anchor and only the label be displayed,

Comment: Why don't you simply put the anchor tag before the label ?

Comment: @kastulo you could also use css media queries to solve that problem and just hide it with css (http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/). This way it would also work without JS.

Comment: ok i get it that's is incorrect, but i couldn't find any other way to remove the anchor tag via javascript

Comment: Using media queries here clearly looks like a better suited solution.

Comment: but if i have an <a> tag surrounding a <span> and i hide the <a> tag with css, doesn't it hides also the <span> inside?

Comment: @kastulo I don't see in what using a label instead of a span is supposed to make it better.

Comment: no, it doesnt, it's just that i have a big markup and i didn't want it to change all of them in my code, but i guess i will change the labels for spans, thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 2):

Use this piece of css on your `label`:

**Css code:**

```
label.autor{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: if i do this, only the span.by will have the cursor, not the whole thing

Comment: with the new edit it will, change `span.by`  for `label.autor`

Answer (score 2):

As stated by others, it is not valid to put a label inside an anchor tag, but if you really want to do it add the following css code to solve your problem:

```
a label { cursor: pointer; }
```

Normally you use a label to point to a specific input field so when you click on the label the input field gets focused. Since you don't reference to an input field the label isn't really useful within the anchor tag.