# Why is the hashtag used for an achor link's placeholder?

Tags: php, html, get

I often see on other sites and within tutorials that when an anchor has a greater purpose than to just be a link, it often has a hashtag (`#`) as the value of the `href` attribute.  I am creating a series of lists within lists in a project that I am currently working on and I am tempted to do this myself but I am afraid that this could potentially complicate systems that the other developers in the team are working on being that this hashtag appears in the address bar post-click.

Are there downsides to voiding a href this way?  I'm assuming it doesn't due to this method's popular use, but is it possible that the hashtag could mess up a function that uses `GET`?

Comment: the anchor should only be used to link\reference part of a page. if you just want to change the cursor? use css (cursor:**)

Comment: @Dagon What if a link is part of a class whose action is determined by jQuery? Rollover the share/edit/delete/flag links under the post, what I am asking is why is the hashtag used as that placeholder and if using the hashtag could create any issues in other relevant coding languages?

Comment: Actually, after answering, I realized it's a dup: [How can I make the cursor a hand when a user hovers over a list item?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3087975/938236)

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos The post is much less about the cursor than it is about using the hashtag in the `href` spot, nobody has addressed why this is done yet - which is the actual question.

Comment: well that's why you post single questions, its difficult to answer when you post several like that. the # is only seen browser side, so it can only effect client side languages.

Comment: not sure what " voiding a href" means, as to downsides -no but don't just throw it in for 'fun'

Comment: Also, "hashtag" seems to be a retcon, I don't think it was used before Twitter :P

Comment: @icedwater is it more commonly referred to as the _pound sign_?

Comment: North America's call it a pound because they don't know what a real **£** is

Comment: @joshie yeah, or the *hash symbol*, *hex sign*, or any other combination thereof. The other thing I just thought of is that *hashtag* doesn't just mean the '#' symbol, it should be an attribute or a summary of some sort to permit searching, e.g. **#pedantic**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No worries,, the "hash tag" is fine to use, has been part of the standard for a decade, and doesn't affect GET. The "anchor tag" `<a>` is originally for this  purpose.

You can use it to create "jump links" to skip to different parts of the document (anchors, as is used on the HTML specification doc pages themselves), or as a "hashbang" in combination with javascript.

What you should NOT do is use the `<a>` tag only to get a pointer cursor for no reason. That said, if the thing does something when you click it (usually why you put a pointer cursor on something), either by changing the hash, linking to a new document, or triggering a javascript function, there's no reason not to use an anchor tag, nor is it bad practice.

When you see an anchor with only `"#"` as the `href`, that usually indicates the developer intends to apply a javascript listener to the element. The empty anchor acts as a do-nothing fallback in case the client doesn't have javascript available. In that case, the user clicks the link and nothing happens. If you are using progressive enhancement principles, then you might put a non-javascript URI equivalent in there instead.

**Documentation**

- HTML Links and anchors - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html
- onhashchange on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange

Comment: +1, great explanation, I'd only add that the hashtags are widely used in HTML templates.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments, don't include HTML markup exclusively for visual 'beauty'. That's the task of CSS and you should learn to [separate concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). For HTML/CSS: HTML = information, CSS = presentation. Ask yourself what's what next time you face a similar problem. Personally, I would create a [CSS class like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3087975/938236):

```
.handy{
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Then add the class to every element needed:

```
<ul id = "menu">
  <li></li>
  <li class = "handy"></li>
</ul>
```

Another way of doing it, depending on your case, is to write the CSS like this:

```
#menu li {
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Comment: So using the hashtag is indeed a bad practice?  So I should apply the CSS to my anchors then?  Because unless it has the `href` in it, the rollover does not show the pointer cursor.

Comment: No, the hash tag is fine, part of the standard for a decade, and doesn't affect GET.

Comment: @Joshie , it's not a bad practice by itself, but the only place I've seen a single hashtag with *some* sense is in HTML templates (which you'll later replace for your actual links). Why are you adding anchors? It seems only to make the cursor look like a pointer. If you are doing so then that's a bad practice indeed.