# Change the mouse pointer on ngclick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I've a `div` with the Angular `ng-click` directive attached to it. On hovering over this element the mouse pointer doesn't change. Is there a way to change it through CSS? I know I can simply attach an anchor tag to it, but I would like to know if this can be done.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

> Is there a way to change it through css?

Yes, see [`cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).

If you just wanted to target elements with the `ng-click` attribute, for example:

```css
[ng-click],
[data-ng-click],
[x-ng-click] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to add an exception to this? F.I. All ng-clicks should have pointer as cursor except the ones that have X class(or any other CSS attribute)

Comment: @Murilo, yes. For example, `.x[ng-click] { cursor: default; }`

Comment: Does anyone know how to accomplish this in Angular 2? Angular 1 used `ng-click` whereas Angular 2 uses `(click)`.

Comment: For angular 2 have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58716247/how-to-apply-cursor-pointer-property-to-click-event-handler
This solution uses a directive to achieve this, so it is not a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 23):

All you have to do is use the [cursor](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) property

```
<div data-ng-click="myFun()" class="pointer"></div>

.pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Can be done via css, just add:

```
.yourClass { cursor: pointer; }
```

To your stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

If you are using datatables, you have to override the default datatables.css settings and add the following code to custom CSS, In the code below row-select is the class that I added on datatables in my HTML page.

```
table.row-select.dataTable tbody td
{
cursor: pointer;    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can achieve it simply through CSS, nothing special about AngularJS here.

```
<div ng-click="myAngularFunctionWithinController()" style="cursor: hand;cursor: pointer;">
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you setting `cursor` twice?

Comment: Because it will cover all cases, all browsers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-a-hand-when-a-user-hovers-over-a-list-item

Comment: `cursor:pointer` will immediately override `cursor:hand` and there aren't any browsers in the wild today that don't correctly support this property (did you actually read the thread you linked to?). Also, applying the style inline isn't going to suit OP's use-case unless he adds that to every element that has an `ng-click` attribute, which really defeats the purpose of using CSS at all.