# How to apply cursor-pointer property to (click) event handler?

Tags: css, angular

```
<i class="cursor-pointer" (click)="sort()"></i>
```

Our codebase has a lot of redundant classes like this. I was looking for a way to apply the cursor pointer property anytime there is a (click) event handler.

Before angular 2, you were able to apply css to angular attributes, but that is no longer possible. [Change the mouse pointer on ngclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896859/change-the-mouse-pointer-on-ngclick)

```
[ng-click]{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible mate, you really need to create a class for this like you did

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a directive that selects all the elements with click binding and apply the style.

**click.cursor.directive.ts:**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[click]'
})
export class ClickCursorDirective {
  @HostBinding('style.cursor') cursor: string = 'pointer';
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div (click)="onClick()">Button</div>
```

Here is a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxpavm-aymrcz)

Comment: Can you show how you would use this in the html?

Would it look like
`<div (click)="onClick()" [click]></div>`

Because if so that seems to me to be even worse than
`div (click)="onClick() class="cursor-pointer"></div>`

Comment: No, all you need to do is having a click binding. I'm adding a stackblitz demo too.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed!