# How do I make the cursor stay as a pointer on text using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, cursor

I just want the cursor to stay a pointer when it passes over the text in my div. Using cs, it works, but using Jquery it reverts to the text selector over text.

This doesn't work...

```
<style>
#test
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: blue;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    font-size: 80px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">It's not a pointer!</div>
<script src='jquery-1.10.2.min.js'>
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testjquery").hover(function(){
        $(this).css({'cursor':'hand', 'cursor':'pointer'});
    });
});
</script>
```

While this works fine...

```
<style>
#test
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: blue;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    font-size: 80px;
}
#test:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">It's a pointer!</div>
```

It seems weird, as I thought jquery simply accessed the css methods.
Looking for an explanation, or better yet a solution w/ how to do this in Jquery. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div id is `test` not `testjquery`

```
$("#test").hover(function () {
    $(this).css({
        'cursor': 'hand',
        'cursor': 'pointer'
    });
});
```

---

Update you can only use

```
$("#test").hover(function () {
    $(this).css({
        'cursor': 'pointer'
    });
});
```

Read [How can I make the cursor a hand when a user hovers over a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975) as commented by [frnhr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236195/frnhr)

Comment: Honest question: do we really need cursor:hand?

Comment: To answer my own question: no :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-a-hand-when-a-user-hovers-over-a-list-item