# Why is img.onclick not functioning?

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

I have this code but the `img.onclick` isn't functioning and couldn't figure out what's the reason. Could someone give me some advice? Thanks

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "images/tv.jpg";
img.width = "280";
img.height = "200";
img.onclick = function () {
    window.location.href = "~/HEMS/EditDevice.cshtml";
}

...............

cell.appendChild(img);`
```

Comment: The `href` you're trying to set gives the impression of a local file (presumably on Linux/Unix?), try using an absolute path with the `file:///` protocol (using triple-slash notation if you choose to omit the `localhost` host-name from the URL)

Comment: Given the file extension I suspect it's a .NET relative location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5WcR4/1/)

It is working perfectly, You need to make sure that url is correct for changing page location:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "images/tv.jpg";
img.width = "280";
img.alt='Url not exist';
img.height = "200";
img.onclick = function () {
    alert('1');
}

document.getElementById("cell").appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "images/tv.jpg";
    img.width = "280";
    img.height = "200";
    img.onClick = function () {
        window.location.href = "~/HEMS/EditDevice.cshtml";
    }

    ...............

    cell.appendChild(img);
```

I believe it's onClick not onclick.

In addition the url you're redirecting to appears to be an MVC page using tilda notation, as this is a server side concept this is not going to work in JavaScript.

Comment: I was referring to the casing - js is case sensitive

Comment: Worth a shot - I assume the image is displaying ok?

Comment: yup, all the images are displaying on the page, but couldn't click on it

Comment: Can you put an alert box in there to confirm - I wouldn't expect tilda notation to work client side and MVC could be hiding errors.

Comment: Replace the window.location.href... with alert('test'); this will help to prove whether it's the click which isn't working or the redirect.

Comment: but the problem I'm facing now is that I couldn't click on the image

Comment: it's the click event function which is not working, the mouse cursor doesn't change when it's over the image, I believe the mouse cursor will change when it's on the image, right?

Comment: As you've wired the click dynamically that may well be a css issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-a-hand-when-a-user-hovers-over-a-list-item

Comment: nah, that's not the problem. 
I believe it's the "img.onclick" not functioning, the problem I'm having is that I couldn't click on the images created using img object

Comment: Refer to @ZaheerAhmed 's answer - he's confirmed my suspicions about the tilda

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
    content
</div>


<script type="application/javascript">
var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "grid.png";
    img.width = "280";
    img.height = "200";
    img.onclick = function () {
        window.location.href = "~/HEMS/EditDevice.cshtml";
    }    
var cnt = document.getElementById('content');
    cnt.appendChild(img);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```