# How can I stop my cursor changing to an I bar when I hover over text in a table?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table and I put a double click on the rows. The table is read only except for some `<input>` fields.

How can I make it so that the cursor does not change to an I bar when I hover over the text that's not an `<input>` field?

I received some answers but they just point to links. Can someone give me an example in a fiddle ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make the cursor a hand when a user hovers over a list item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-a-hand-when-a-user-hovers-over-a-list-item)

Comment: You can restrict user to select the text by `user-select: none;`. Add vendor prefix for browser compatibility. Although user can select the text by other methods.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a CSS property called `cursor` to specify what your cursor will turn into when you scroll over the text. You can see some of the examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).

And here is a default cursor on a table example. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2PH2k/).

Answer (score 8):

```css
.your-block {
  cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

set cursor property for the field you want to be some thing like pointer,waiting etc

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: If I set that for the table then how can I make it different for the input ?

Comment: table must be having <td> and inside the <td> their will be some component may be a div may be an input field. you can set cursor for them separately dont set it for table set it for child components

Answer (score -1):

use this css:

```
table.className td input{
   cursor: none; /* or the one which you would like to have */
}
```

Comment: But how can I make it just stay as the normal type of cursor for the table?

Comment: @Melina `cursor: default;`