# how to change the text cursor specifically using css

Tags: css

I want to change the beam looking I thing that appears when you hover over text. However, I've only been able to change the pointer cursor. Is this possible in CSS?

Edit: I wanna change the way the text version of the cursor looks like. Instead of being the I beam, I want it to be a custom image. Is this possible?

Comment: According to this answer, it should be possible just using the cursor property... https://stackoverflow.com/a/20988528/5008997

Comment: That *is* the cursor. You change it in the same way. [Edit] the question to show what you've tried and isn't working.

Comment: I wanna change the way the text version of the cursor looks like. Instead of being the I beam, I want it to be a custom image. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use css to style the cursor with " cursor: someStyleName "

ex that makes it a crosshair:

span.myclass {

cursor: crosshair;

}

this link shows a use (in html, but the code is the same in css) and a demo of what it looks like, as well as many of the different style types:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor

ps: this site in general is great for web dev info.. even java/jquery stuff.

Comment: I wanna change the way the text version of the cursor looks like. Instead of being the I beam, I want it to be a custom image. Is this possible?