# How do I make my "X" look like a hand or arrow hovering over it while closing out my Div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright, I know how to close the div using a "p" tag just fine with jQuery.  The code for that is below.  However I don't want the client to have a cursor appear over the "X", I want the "X" to be an arrow hovering over it or a hand like it would be with an "a" tag.  However when I use an "a" tag it reloads the page which defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do.  Logically I would think I would need to use the preventDefault() syntax, but I tried that, but maybe I didn't do it right since I'm a noob.  Any help would be apperciated.

Jquery below...

```
    function closer() {
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#closeX").click(function(){
              $("#closeX").hide();
              $("#popArt").hide();
            });
        });
    }
```

HTML Below...

```
       <div id="popArt">
           <div><p id="closeX" onclick="closer()"><strong>X</strong></p>
               <div><img src="../images/pcTuneUp.jpg" align="left"></div><br />
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eu nibh eu ipsum ultricies consectetur. Vivamus nunc mi, rhoncus vitae velit sed, ornare dapibus tellus. Ut posuere<a href="#">Read More</a>  </p>
           </div>
       </div>
```

CSS Below...

```
  section#right div#popArt div p#closeX{
     padding: 2px;
     float: right;
     border: 2px solid black;
     border-radius: 100px;
     color: black;
  }

  section#right div#popArt{
     position: fixed;
     right: 3px;
     top: 320px;

     width: 310px;
     height: 145px;
     border: 2px solid rgb(229, 238, 222);
     background-color: rgb(221, 230, 222);

     visibility: hidden;  //don't worry about the visibility as hidden that is for another javascript event.  switch to visible or delete when testing.
```

Like I said it works like it should as is, but I don't want a cursor.

Comment: CSS `cursor: pointer`;

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something simple.  I actually never been taught about cursor: or don't remember seeing it.  I will remember that in the future.  Deep down I figured I didn't have to change any code (jquery), but didn't know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make the cursor a hand when a user hovers over a list item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-a-hand-when-a-user-hovers-over-a-list-item)

Comment: I didn't know about cursor, sorry if it was or potentially a duplicate question Justin.  If I known about cursor there would not of been a question and therefor no duplicate.  So penalize me if you must, but seriously I didn't know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your css file, add `cursor:pointer` to `section#right div#popArt div p#closeX`. This way, your cursor will change for a hand while hovering you "X".

Answer (score 1):

Set the cursor with CSS:

```
#closeX {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

OR, use the `<a>` tag but `return false` so the href isn't loaded:

```
$("#closeX").click(function(){
    $("#closeX").hide();
    $("#popArt").hide();
    return false;
});
```