# Is cursor type pointer deprecated?

Tags: html, css, cursor

I tried using `cursor:pointer` to my `div` but still I get the default cursor type on hovering it. What am I doing wrong?

I checked other live sites also, this problem resides all over. Not sure whether it has been deprecated or I'm doing something wrong.

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
div:hover{
  cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting the hand while hovering over it - is that your intended outcome?

Comment: I always do `cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;` cause of some old legacy browser from 16 years ago. it's stuck in my system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make the cursor a hand when a user hovers over a list item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-a-hand-when-a-user-hovers-over-a-list-item)

Comment: it's working fine in chrome, safari, mozilla

Comment: It works good as expected.

Comment: try on other browsers

Comment: Using Mac OS - chrome latest version

Comment: @Santosh This is working perfectly on a windows and a friend's Mac. Googled a bit , and someone had suggested , if your PS is open in your Mac... restart the application, seems to work !! ...  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @luciferous OS-X Yosemite im using

Comment: Just as a side note, you don't need to use `:hover`, the cursor property works exactly the same way if you put it where the other div properties are. This shouldn't be causing the problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

As you may check in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/cursor), this is not deprecated. Browser compatibility information is also present on this web site.

You can check the compatibility with this web [site](http://caniuse.com/#search=cursor). to get the full info.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your swift response. You guys wont believe it. As suggested by luciferous in the comment. I tried tring off photoshop. It worked like a GEM. But dunno what could be the reason for photoshop turning off to deal with browser cursor pointer. But still issue has been resolved. This might be funny solution but it worked

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
div:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

By using two properties repeatedly, the one with the invalid/not supported value will be ignored as per css spec, and the next line will be executed.

I'm using this for years, since the netscape navigator/internet explorer wars, and aparently sometimes it's still needed to use both.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor pointer is not depricated, it might be some bug in your browser. In this example you can differentiate between cursor type.
 [Also check this website for reference](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-cursors)

```css
#a1{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
#a2{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
}
#a3{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:green;
}
#a3:hover{
  cursor:default
}
#a2:hover{
  cursor:pointer
}
#a1:hover{
  cursor:help
}
```

```html
<div id="a1">

</div>
<div id="a2">

</div >
<div id="a3">

</div >
```