# Would it be possible to make sure that when a cursor hovers over a certain area, it would not change to "hand"?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/gkys5Lpo/24/), the desired result would be that when the cursor hovers over the legend, the mouse would not change to hand. How can I achieve it?

I am not sure, but would something like this be useful?

```
window.setTimeout("document.body.style.cursor = 'hand';", 2000);
```

Comment: Use CSS to specify the cursor type when hovering over the legend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make the cursor a hand when a user hovers over a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-a-hand-when-a-user-hovers-over-a-list-item)

Comment: I recommend this post from CSS tricks: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a bit of css.

```
g.highcharts-legend, g.highcharts-legend-item tspan{
  cursor:crosshair
}
```

(Ive used `crosshair` just for demonstration, you can chose [any value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor))

http://jsfiddle.net/gkys5Lpo/27/

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply this css:

```
.inactive-link {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```