# Should a cursor only be applied on :hover?

Tags: css, css-selectors

For any element, we can specify which cursor should show when hovering the item using e.g.

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Is it better to specify this rule only on `:hover` ([as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41462592/3744304)),

```
.my-element:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

or to the element without any pseudo class (since it will only affect the user interface on hover anyway, as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3088012/3744304))

```
.my-element {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Which would be preferrable?

What would be the pros/cons of either way?