# Arrow cursor changes to vertical bar while hovering over h1

Tags: html

I have a simple code

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

When I open this .html file inside Firefox browser, when I hover cursor over `Hello`, cursor changes from arrow to a vertical bar. Why is this so ? Is this because Firefox's default style sheet ?

Comment: will it help you? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/how-to-change-the-cursor-into-a-hand-when-a-user-hovers-over-a-list-item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all text tags "vertical bar", this means that you can select text and copy it.
If you want change cursor on hover effect, use css with option `cursor`.
[cursors documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) and [about custom cursors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property)

```css
html {
  background: hsl(0, 2%, 11%);
  background-image: url(https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/guacamole-green/cursor-3-xxl.png);
}
h1 {
margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  color: grey;
}
#auto {
  cursor: auto;
}
#pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#default {
  cursor: default;
}
#you-own-cursor {
  cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='18' height='20' viewBox='0 0 18 20' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M1.5 2.32471L16.5 18.1737' stroke='%23F986A1' stroke-width='3' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='bevel'/%3E%3Cpath d='M16.5 2.32471L1.50005 18.1737' stroke='%23F986A1' stroke-width='3' stroke-linecap='round'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") 5 5, pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="auto">Hello</h1>
<h1 id="pointer">Hello</h1>
<h1 id="default">Hello</h1>
<h1 id="you-own-cursor">Hello</h1>
```

Comment: Is this because of Firefox's default stylesheet ? Where can I see documentation for this ?